# Find the equation of the line of intersection of the planes; 13x +13y-6z=8 , 2x + 2y -6z=22

Tags: vectors

I don't know how to go about it ; my answers are far behind the objectives l  have.The objs. are in the form 
x-a=-y-b=z-c=0

Comment: Okay, I found it!  Now what?

Answer (score 2):

You have the following 2 equations:

$$13x + 13y -6z=8, \quad 2x+2y-6z=22.$$

Looking at the second one, we can find $z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$:

$$6z = 2x + 2y -22,$$

then plugging this into the first equation

$$13x + 13y - 2x - 2y + 22 = 8 \implies 11y + 11x + 14 =0$$

and this is the equation of the line of intersection.

Answer (score 0):

The general method to solve these problems is to solve the system of linear equations. This can be done by converting it into a matrix equation and then using elementary row operations to obtain a solution space.

In your example, the system of equations is $$\begin{cases}13x+13y-6z=8\\2x+2y-6z=22\end{cases}$$
which corresponds the augmented matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}13&13&-6&|&8\\2&2&-6&|&22\end{bmatrix}$$
Row reduce the above augmented matrix to obtain the solution space, which will be the line of intersection of the given planes (if such a line exists).